# Javascript equivalent of $('input[name$="value"]') in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I get an input element whose name attribute ends with a particular value using just javascript?

I found this `$('input[name$="value"]')` method available in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Is there a function like that available in javascript? I cannot use jQuery for some reason.

Comment: JQuery is written in javascript, so include the JQuery source in your function :P

Comment: He said he couldn't use jQuery.

Comment: For some reason? Fix that reason instead of working around it.

Comment: If you can't add a single `<script>` tag, could you change your markup?

Comment: "I cannot use jQuery for some reason." screams "This is homework"

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408040/search-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: @Jleagle That reason is personal preference. I just don't want to. Can't fix that reason :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned this yet. Have you tried:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="value"]');
```

This will only work if the browser supports the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) method but it is what jQuery uses underneath if support is found.

Here's the table that lists browser support for the method:

[When can I use querySelector/querySelectorAll?](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: Fifty seconds ahead of me...sigh... =/ +1

Comment: That's a great answer. +1 I may just go and delete mine now. :/

Comment: Why even bother posting this? The OP learns nothing. There are much better options available.

Comment: @MattMcDonald - The OP most definitely did learn something. They learned the proper way to select elements from the DOM using selectors without the need for a 3rd party library (querySelector and querySelectorAll are built in to the browser).

Comment: @MattMcDonald I would say the OP accepting the answer conflicts with your assertion

Comment: I just posted an answer for the community to consider. Its approach works in far more browsers and does not ignore the DOM API.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName("value")[0]);
```

Or if you want to find the first `input` element with "value" in its name:

```
var searchString = "value";
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), wantedElem;

for(var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(elems[i].name.lastIndexOf(searchString) == elems[i].name.length-searchString.length) {
        wantedElem = elems[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(wantedElem);
```

Comment: Change it to `if(elems[i].name.lastIndexOf("value") == elems[i].name.length-5` and it should fetch only those elements ENDING on "value"

Comment: name$=value doesn't mean that there is an attribute "name$" but rather that there is an attribute "name" ending on the given value

Comment: Oh, woops, fixing. Misunderstood the question. :I

Comment: If you get rid of the "-1" after .length it will do the trick :)

Comment: @devnull69: `length` is one longer than the actual index we're looking for (strings are 0-indexed) so I believe that is correct.

Comment: Valient try, @ElliotBonneville.  This is precisely why node.js exists and why jQuery is based on it.

Comment: Wait, what? jQuery isn't based off of node.js, that's a serverside Javascript framework, jQuery is a DOM-manipulation library, the two are nothing alike... right? Also, thank you, I'm flattered.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Try it ... the length is one longer than the index, that is correct. Now substract 1 from the length and you are on the "e" of value, substract 2 and you are on the "u" ... go on until you substract 5 and you are on the "v" which is the actual index and 5 is the length of the searchString.... not -1

Comment: +1'd. And shouldn't `wantedElem = elems[i]; break;` be inside braces?

Comment: I think I saw a unclosed `(` on the second line, also on the loop `; len` is meant to be a comma

Comment: Yep, you did. :I Next time I'm going to run my stuff through jsFiddle. *Before* posting it. All corrections are correct, heh. I think I'll go crawl back under my rock now. -.-

Comment: Anyways thanks man. I will use the querySelector for now. But if anybody using dreaded IE complain, I might change back to using your method.

Comment: Okay, cool. No problem, I probably learned just as much as you did. :o

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you've placed these `<input>` elements where they belong (in a `<form>` element).

The easiest way to traverse form controls via the DOM API is via the [`HTMLFormElement::elements`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) `HTMLCollection`. It allows named traversal, which is very handy for specific elements.

For example, consider the following markup:

```
<form action="./" method="post" name="test"
    onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test Controls</legend>
        <input name="control_one" type="text"
            value="One">
        <input name="control_two" type="text"
            value="Two">
        <input name="control_three" type="text"
            value="Three">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Following that, some simple document tree traversal is required. Here's the entirety of it:

```
var test = document.forms.test,
    controls = test.elements;

function traverseControl(control)
{
    var patt = /one$/,
        match = patt.test(control.name);
    if (match) {
        // do something
        console.log(control);
    }
}

function traverseControls(nodes)
{
    var index;
    if (typeof nodes === "object" &&
        nodes.length) {
        index = nodes.length - 1;
        while (index > -1) {
            traverseControl(
                nodes[index]
            );
            index -= 1;
        }
    }
}

traverseControls(controls);
```

As you can see, it really isn't too difficult. The upshot of using `HTMLCollection`s is the support of browsers old and new. Since `HTMLCollection`s were implemented in DOM 0, they're widely supported.

In the future, I'd suggest using traversal that's far less vague. If you're in control of the document tree being traversed (i.e. you wrote the markup), you should already know the `name`s of controls. Otherwise, vague approaches like the preceding must be used.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/epusow

For more, [this article](http://fortybelow.ca/hosted/comp-lang-javascript/faq/notes/form-access/) can be perused.

Answer (score -1):

This method returns an array of elements

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("value");
```

Comment: Downvote because while the answer is correct it's not comparable to the problem described in the question. It's [name$="value"] ... mind the $

Comment: This gets anything with name "value", where his selector grabs only input tags.

Comment: Yes, you want `getElementsByTag("input")`, then iterate through that array to find the element ending in "value".